# std::string defined in a function retains its previous value?

Tags: c++

If a string is defined in a function, does it retain its value between calls ?

Something like this :

```
std::string myFunction( std::string input)
{
    std::string output;

    for ( int i=0; i < input.length(); i++ )
    {
        output[i] = input[i];
    }

    return output;

}
```

If the input string's length is longer in the first call to the function than the length of the input in the second call, then the string returned in the second call still has last few(same as the difference in length) characters of the previous call intact.

Comment: Why don't you simply write `std::string output = input;` instead of the loop? Or even better, replace the entire body with `return input;`?

Comment: @FredOverflow thats just a sample code, actual code do a lot more then that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a string is defined in a function, does it retain its value between calls ?

In well-defined code it doesn't, unless it's declared `static`.

The main problem with your current implementation is the body of the loop:

```
for ( int i=0; i < input.length(); i++ )
{
    output[i] = input[i];
}
```

Here, you're assigning past the end of `output`, which is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Once you're in the realm of undefined behaviour, anything can happen.

Comment: Not disagreeing with your answer, but just curious, if he's not using `static`, is the allocation for `output` always in the same block?

Comment: @NPE If a string is defined like std::string output; How its length is decided ?

Comment: @StudentX: The length is zero. Thus assigning to *any* `output[i]` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @NPE makes sense. And correct way is ? Use a char *output ? or char output[input.length()] ?

Comment: @StudentX: One way is to resize the string so that it's long enough to hold the output: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. I believe you ask this about a string and not about every other local variable, since a string uses the heap. That's right, but string also has a destructor, which is called upon exiting from scope, deallocating the heap it used.

Of course, you might find that it did retain its value, but that would be just a coincidence of allocating the same memory area again (which might happen again and again, depending on your program, memory environment, compiler, etc..).

Comment: Yes that's what I thought, that it must be coincidence. Was confused why it was initialing to the same memory address.